# Avoiding the "Pyramid of Doom" like syntax with urllib, urllib2 and request

Tags: python, request, urllib, try-except

It's hard to write Python2 and Python3 and `request` dependencies code for the responses because they `urlopen()` functions and `requests.get()` function return different types:

- Python2 `urllib.request.urlopen()` returns a `http.client.HTTPResponse`
- Python3 `urllib.urlopen(url)` returns an `instance`
- Request `request.get(url)` returns a `requests.models.Response`

To support both Python2 and Python3 and users that doesn't want to install the `request` dependency, I've tried a "Pyramid of Doom" looking `try-except` in the import and the `get_content()` function:

```
try: # Try importing requests first.
    import requests
except ImportError: 
    try: # Try importing Python3 urllib
        import urllib.request
    except AttributeError: # Now importing Python2 urllib
        import urllib


def get_content(url):
    try:  # Using requests.
        return requests.get(url).content # Returns requests.models.Response.
    except NameError:  
        try: # Using Python3 urllib.
            with urllib.request.urlopen(index_url) as response:
                return response.read() # Returns http.client.HTTPResponse.
        except AttributeError: # Using Python3 urllib.
            return urllib.urlopen(url).read() # Returns an instance.
```

**Are there other ways to achieve the same result of returning the read content and avoiding the nested `try-except`?**

Comment: If you don't want `requests` as a dependency, why bother using `requests` at all? If you're going through the trouble to make it work with `urllib` alone, just use `urllib`. I think you have the your bullet points for Python 2 and 3 `urllib` backwards. [Python-Future](http://python-future.org/compatible_idioms.html#urllib-module) suggests using `requests` for this reason. However, see "# Python 2 and 3: alternative 4" for a `urllib`-only alternative that should only require `try` for `import`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What is the benefit to your users in using `requests`? It's easier to simply ignore `requests` and support the standard library functions. That can be done transparently to the rest of your code by importing like this:

```
try:
    from urllib.request import urlopen
except ImportError:
    from urllib2 import urlopen
```

From then on all GET requests can be issued with `urlopen(url)`. The returned data can be retrieved with `read()`.

Now, if you really want to proceed with `requests` support, you could write the import code along with the definition of `get_content()` like this:

```
try:
    import requests
    get_content = lambda url : requests.get(url).content
except ImportError:
    try:                   # Python 3
        from urllib.request import urlopen
    except ImportError:    # Python2
        from urllib2 import urlopen
    get_content = lambda url : urlopen(url).read()
```

Answer (score 1):

As everyone has mentioned you should not bother too much about requests, if you are going the route of urllib. But if you still want to get away from too many nested exceptions, you can use something like below

```
import sys
key = str(sys.version_info.major)

try:  # Try importing requests first.
    import requests
    key = "requests"
except ImportError:
    try:  # Try importing Python3 urllib
        import urllib.request
    except (AttributeError, ImportError):  # Now importing Python2 urllib
        import urllib

FUNC = {
    "2": {
        "urlopen": lambda url: urllib.urlopen(url),
        "read": lambda res: res.read()
    },
    "requests": {
        "urlopen": lambda url: requests.get(url),
        "read": lambda res: res.content
    },
    "3": {
        "urlopen": lambda url: urllib.request.urlopen(url),
        "read": lambda res: res.read()
    },
}

urlopen = FUNC[key]["urlopen"]
read = FUNC[key]["read"]

def get_content(url):
    res = urlopen(url)
    return read(res)

print(get_content("http://tarunlalwani.com"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to import all three libraries as `request`, and check for attributes in the `get_content` function to identify the imported library.
As an alternative to nested try-except blocks, you could import `requests` in a separate try-except block, 
so that it will override `urllib` / `urllib2`, if the module is installed.

```
try: 
    import urllib.request as request
except ImportError: 
    import urllib2 as request
try: 
    import requests as request
except ImportError:
    pass

def get_content(url):
    return request.get(url).content if hasattr(request, 'get') else request.urlopen(url).read()
```

This results in clean and sipmle code, and allows you to sumbit more complex requests, example,

```
def get_content(url, headers={}):
    if hasattr(request, 'get'):
        return request.get(url, headers=headers).content
    else:
        return request.urlopen(request.Request(url, headers=headers)).read()
```